# Pseudo-Element and listening to a transition to end

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having a navigation which has pseudo-elements as icons (a:before).

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">click me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">click me</a></li>
</ul>
<style>
  /* that's a placeholder for the icon */
  a:before {
    content : 'X';
    width:1em;height:1em;line-height:1em;font-size:1em;
    border-radius : 50%; background-color : blue;
  }
</style>
```

If I click on an anchor, I want this icon to spin. I'm doing it via jQuery .on('click') and adding class that has a CSS-Transition. This works good.

Check out this fiddle, it's pretty simple:

> https://jsfiddle.net/14yet0ts/1/

...

**The Problem**

However, after a short amount of time (I'm using setTimeout() in my jsFiddle to simulate an ajax request), I want the CSS-Transition to end after it has completed.

I have seen, that there are transitionend-events that jQuery can listen to, however I cannot listen to it, because the transition is set on the pseudo-element of the  tag, which is not accessible via DOM.

Is there any possibility to listen to the transition to end, without changing the HTML?

Mainly it's this part of the script that's not working:

```
$('a:before', el).one('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd', function(){
    alert('2: transition ended, remove class loading');
    el.removeClass('loading');
});
```

Cheers

Comment: Your animation is infinite.  I'm not sure you can have an event when it "ends".  Are you trying to avoid stopping the animation while the X is sideways so you want to know when the current rotation ends?

Comment: Yes, I want the X to spin while an ajax request is loading. If the ajax request is done, I want the X to finish the "round", so it doesn't look un-smooth :) Yes, I'd like to know when the current rotation ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you aren't using a transition, you are using an animation.  As a result, you need to use the animation-related events.  In this case, you want `animationiteration`.

Finally, you can't listen for the event on the pseudo-element itself.  However, the event bubbles to the `a` so you can listen there:

```
function removeTransition(el) {
    //  this does not work!
    $('a', el).one('animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration oanimationiteration MSAnimationIteration', function(){
        el.removeClass('loading');
    });    
}
```

**You also need to remove the alerts because they prevent the smooth transition**

https://jsfiddle.net/14yet0ts/3/

---

Another note unrelated to the exact question posed, you should update your code to only remove the class from the clicked `li`, otherwise you will have issues if multiple animations are going at once.

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    var wait = 1000 + Math.floor(Math.random()*2)*1000;

    // el is the exact `li`, not all loading `li` elements
    var el = $(this).closest('li').addClass('loading');
    e.preventDefault();

    setTimeout(function() {
        removeTransition(el);
    }, wait);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/14yet0ts/4/

Comment: Hey, that worked! Genius! I was already playing with adding another class which sets `-webkit-animation-iteration-count : 1;`, and then remove it after 1 second, lol.

Comment: @Boris just updated with one more note.  You'll want to make that update or concurrent animations will mess up.

Comment: Yeah, will have to integrate this one as well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JamesMontagne - Great work but there is a typo in the accepted solution. The first event name in the jquery event listener is 'nimationiteration'. It is spelled correctly in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the `:focus` CSS pseudo selector for this, removing the need for jQuery at all.

```css
 /* that's a placeholder for the icon */
 a:before {
   content: 'X';
   width: 1em;
   height: 1em;
   line-height: 1em;
   font-size: 1em;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background-color: blue;
 }
 a:focus:before {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
   transform: rotate(360deg);
   transition: all 0.4s;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">click me</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">click me</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

An alternative would be to use animation keyframes:

```css
/* that's a placeholder for the icon */

a:before {
  content: 'X';
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}
a:focus:before {
  -webkit-animation: 4s rotateMe linear forwards;
  animation: 4s rotateMe linear forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateMe {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotateMe {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">click me</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">click me</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**As per your comment**

in order to generate this 'random timeout', I would use a class toggle.

However, this still does not allow a 'smooth finish' before stopping

In other words, something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("myClass");

  });
  $('#stop').click(function(){
    $('a').removeClass("myClass")
    });

});
```

```css
/* that's a placeholder for the icon */

a:before {
  content: 'X';
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.myClass:before {
  -webkit-animation: 4s rotateMe linear  infinite;
  animation: 4s rotateMe linear  infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateMe {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotateMe {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">click me</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">click me</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<button id="stop">button to play the 'stop' action</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still trying to figure out keyframes. I want the X to spin infinite until another event happens (the timeout with the random value). After that, I want to finish the current rotation and then remove the animation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $('a').on('click', function(e) {
    var wait = 1000 + Math.floor(Math.random()*2)*1000;
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('loading');
    e.preventDefault();
    
    setTimeout(function() {
        var el = $('li.loading');
        alert('1: wait countdown ended, start listening to transition to end one last time');
        removeTransition(el);
    }, wait);
});

function removeTransition(el) {
    //  this does not work!   
        alert('2: transition ended, remove class loading');
        el.removeClass('loading');

}
```

```css
/* global */
ul,li{list-style-type:none;margin:15px;}

/* anchor */
a:before {
    content : 'X';
    display : block;
    background-color : red;
    color : white;
    width:1em;height:1em;line-height:1em;font-size:1em;
    border-radius : 50%;
    float:left;text-align:Center;
}

/* loading animation */
li.loading a {
    color : green;
    text-decoration : none;
}
li.loading > a:before {
    -webkit-animation-name : rotate;
    -webkit-animation-duration : 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count : infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function : linear;
    -moz-animation-name : rotate;
    -moz-animation-duration : 2s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count : infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function : linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from {-webkit-transform : rotate(0deg);}
    to {  -webkit-transform : rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    from {-moz-transform : rotate(0deg);}
    to {  -moz-transform : rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">click me</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">click me</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">click me</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is working fine for me if I modify the javascript to this...

```
function removeTransition(el) { 
        alert('2: transition ended, remove class loading');
        el.removeClass('loading');

}
```

Comment: That doesn't let the current rotation end, it just jumps directly back to starting position.